# Database - The ID does not run continuously

Tags: python, sql, excel, tkinter, mariadb

Can anyone tell me why the ID does not run continuously in the database.

I am writing data from my Python program (using a GUI I built in TKinter) to a MariaDB. Using HeidiSQL I look at the data. I notice that the ID does not run continuously but has jumps. The ID column is set to be an auto_increment.

[Screenshot Database ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI2dl.jpg)

After talking to my colleague about it, it's not enough that the ID is unique, it must also be continuous.

It seems that this problem only occurs when I call the function to copy data from an Excel file to the database. I tested it again with a different amount of data and the ID jumps exactly as far as there are many rows in Excel. As an example: If there are 8 rows of data in Excel, then the ID jumps by 8 digits.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
16
to
24
32
to
40
```

I'm grateful for any help.

This is the code of the function:

```
    # create window to open excel files
    def openexcel():
        # ---------- Display Settings ---------------
        root_openexcel = tk.Tk()
        root_openexcel.title("Open Excel")
        # root_tgadisp.geometry("370x680")

        root_openexcel.geometry("650x650")  # set the root_openexcel dimensions
        # root_openexcel.pack_propagate(False)  # tells the root_openexcel to not let the widgets inside it determine its size.
        # root_openexcel.resizable(0, 0)  # makes the root_openexcel window fixed in size.

        # Frame for TreeView
        frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(root_openexcel, text="Excel Data")
        frame1.place(height=500, width=600, relx=0.01)

        # Frame for open file dialog
        file_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root_openexcel, text="Open File")
        file_frame.place(height=100, width=600, rely=0.78, relx=0.01)

        # Buttons
        button1 = tk.Button(file_frame, text="Browse A File", command=lambda: File_dialog())
        button1.place(rely=0.65, relx=0.50)

        button2 = tk.Button(file_frame, text="Load File", command=lambda: Load_excel_data())
        button2.place(rely=0.65, relx=0.30)

        button3 = tk.Button(file_frame, text="Load into Database", command=lambda: Load_into_database())
        button3.place(rely=0.65, relx=0.70)

        # The file/file path text
        label_file = ttk.Label(file_frame, text="No File Selected")
        label_file.place(rely=0, relx=0)

        ## Treeview Widget
        tv1 = ttk.Treeview(frame1)
        tv1.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)  # set the height and width of the widget to 100% of its container (frame1).

        treescrolly = tk.Scrollbar(frame1, orient="vertical",
                                   command=tv1.yview)  # command means update the yaxis view of the widget
        treescrollx = tk.Scrollbar(frame1, orient="horizontal",
                                   command=tv1.xview)  # command means update the xaxis view of the widget
        tv1.configure(xscrollcommand=treescrollx.set,
                      yscrollcommand=treescrolly.set)  # assign the scrollbars to the Treeview Widget
        treescrollx.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")  # make the scrollbar fill the x axis of the Treeview widget
        treescrolly.pack(side="right", fill="y")  # make the scrollbar fill the y axis of the Treeview widget


        def File_dialog():
            """This Function will open the file explorer and assign the chosen file path to label_file"""
            filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/Zlatan/Desktop/Project_PolymerSQL",
                                                  title="Select A File",
                                                  filetype=(("xlsx files", "*.xlsx"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
            label_file["text"] = filename
            return None

        def Load_excel_data():
            """If the file selected is valid this will load the file into the Treeview"""
            file_path = label_file["text"]
            try:
                excel_filename = r"{}".format(file_path)
                if excel_filename[-4:] == ".csv":
                    df = pd.read_csv(excel_filename)
                else:
                    df = pd.read_excel(excel_filename)

            except ValueError:
                tk.messagebox.showerror("Information", "The file you have chosen is invalid")
                return None
            except FileNotFoundError:
                tk.messagebox.showerror("Information", f"No such file as {file_path}")
                return None

            clear_data()
            tv1["column"] = list(df.columns)
            tv1["show"] = "headings"
            for column in tv1["columns"]:
                tv1.heading(column, text=column)  # let the column heading = column name

            df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist()  # turns the dataframe into a list of lists
            for row in df_rows:
                tv1.insert("", "end",
                           values=row)  
            return None

        def Load_into_database():
            file_path = label_file["text"]
            try:
                excel_filename = r"{}".format(file_path)
                if excel_filename[-4:] == ".csv":
                    df = pd.read_csv(excel_filename, header=None, names=['Lagerzeit', 'Lager_Temperatur', 'Lager_Medium', 'Datum_Prüfung', 'Order_name', 'Operator_name', 'Sample', 'Strain', 'F_s', 'F_0', 'sigma_s', 'sigma_0', 'A', 'alpha', 'Wert_1', 'Wert_2', 'Wert_3', 'Wert_4'])
                else:
                    df = pd.read_excel(excel_filename, header=None, names=['Lagerzeit', 'Lager_Temperatur', 'Lager_Medium', 'Datum_Prüfung', 'Order_name', 'Operator_name', 'Sample', 'Strain', 'F_s', 'F_0', 'sigma_s', 'sigma_0', 'A', 'alpha', 'Wert_1', 'Wert_2', 'Wert_3', 'Wert_4'])

            except ValueError:
                tk.messagebox.showerror("Information", "The file you have chosen is invalid")
                return None
            except FileNotFoundError:
                tk.messagebox.showerror("Information", f"No such file as {file_path}")
                return None

            engine = create_engine("mariadb+mariadbconnector://root:pwd@127.0.0.1:3306/polymer")
            df.to_sql('tssr', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

        #clear function in openexcel
        def clear_data():
            tv1.delete(*tv1.get_children())
            return None
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with less code? :)

Comment: Is expected Database works at this if has some problem on transaction and do a rollback. The problem is if the data you are saving is not present

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. The main feature of an ID is that it must be **unique**, not strictly sequential.

IDs are not supposed to be continuos, though MariaDB's clause `AUTO_INCREMENT` implies the opposite.

Databases consider IDs as internal values to uniquely identify rows. They are not exposed on the UI or on external interfaces. There's no need to care about its continuity.